# How to pass custom headers in apache Camel Salesforce Component Making REST calls

Tags: spring, java-8, apache-camel, salesforce, integration

I am trying to pass some custom headers in request and trying to marshal the response to my DTO like this but it errors out by saying receiving the headers.Also I did not find any documentation around how can I pass any objectmapper config to the below call so that it directly transforms the json to my custom DTO provided in sObjectClass.

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="x-sfdc-testUUID" id="header1">
  <camel:simple>${headers.test_UUID}</camel:simple>
</camel:setHeader>

<camel:to id="salesforce" uri="salesforce:apexCall?apexMethod=GET&amp;apexUrl=/dummyendpoint/getemployees&amp;rawPayload=true&amp;sObjectClass=test.package.dummypojo"/>
```

I tried passing headers in multiple ways but it seems when I check salesforce logs it does not reach the api the way its expected. Whereas the same call works via POSTAM if I hit the SF api directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use rawHttpHeaders parameter definition :  Comma separated list of message headers to include as HTTP headers

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/salesforce-component.html

Comment: **rawHttpHeaders** only work with `salesforce:raw` calls whereas I am using `salesforce:apexCall` and in documentation it does not say how to pass custom headers.